# Dropdownlist Validation with Submit Button in APS.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist with below values and Submit button at bottom of page

- China
- Japan
- England

I have this dropdownlist placed in gridview  and display the listitem accordingly to the rows. But I have a condition where If the value is China in any row in gridview Then user should be promted with an error message when click on Submit button. Else if any of the rows are not china, then user should proceed.

Comment: what is the problem? to find out the value of the dropdown or to show the error message?

Comment: you must iterate on gridView rows, and then in each row find control that is ddl, and them check it value

Comment: Any sample code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in this.gridView.Rows)
 {
    DropDownList ddl = row.FindControl("ddlName") as DropDownList;
    if(ddl != null)
    {
    //check here
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Button's click, write something like

```
if (!MyDropDownList.Items.FindByValue("China"))
{
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: But my dropdown is placed in ItemTemplate in Gridview. Could you please suggest me any sample code to query among list of records in gridview to fire this condition